# Displaying specific country into map using countries.geojson file?

Tags: openlayers, geojson

I was trying different ways to display one country using countries.geojson file, but I unable to display.
I tried like this, but map is not displaying....

```
var map = new ol.Map({
    layers : [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            source : new ol.source.OSM()
        }),   
        vector],
    target : document.getElementById('map'),
    view : new ol.View({
        center : [ 0,0 ],
        zoom : 4 
    })
});

var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
        url: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openlayers/ol3/6838fdd4c94fe80f1a3c98ca92f84cf1454e232a/examples/data/geojson/countries.geojson'
    }),
    style: function(feature, res){
        if(feature.get("name") == "Germany"){
            return new ol.style.Style({
                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                    color: 'red',
                    width: 2
                })
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Define yor `var vector =...` before adding it to the map!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [`ol.StyleFunction()`](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.html#.StyleFunction) and get the name (or any other - depending on the source) attribute of the feature. E.g.:

```
// vector layer
var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
        url: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openlayers/ol3/6838fdd4c94fe80f1a3c98ca92f84cf1454e232a/examples/data/geojson/countries.geojson'
    }),
    style: function(feature, res){
        // replace "Germany" with any country name you would like to display...
        if(feature.get("name") == "Germany"){
            return new ol.style.Style({
                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                    color: 'red',
                    width: 2
                })
            });
        }
    }
});
```

See Demo on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lars_fiddle/ta54wu27/1/)

Comment: I was tried but map is not displaying

Comment: The code is working. Your error should be somewhere else. I added a fiddle.

Comment: Its working..... thank you :) but, I want to display only selected country remaining should be blur or hide from map,  do you have any idea about this....